# Is it valid to calculate mass of electron using the speed of the wave packet and energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality

A gaussian wave packet. It's peak is moving at speed v. We know the energy of the packet is E. Can I deduce the mass of the electron using $m=2E/v^2$

Answer (score 1):

If E represents only kinetic energy and v is small compared to the speed of light then this is ok. However, the electron mass is already known, why calculate it?